# Showing FileNotFound Error when trying to open file from another directory in python

Tags: python, json, file, machine-learning, visual-studio-code

```
\parentDirectory
    \subdr1
        -testfile.txt
    \subdr2
        \childdir
           -file.json
           -file2.pickle
        -fileOpener.py
```

I would like to read the file.json from fileOpener.py in Python using:

```
with open("./childdir/file.json", 'r') as f:
```

But I'm getting FileNotFoundError.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './childdir/file.json'
```

**Would anyone mind solving this issue?** I'm using WINDOWS operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `fileOpener.py` within the `subdir2` then all is well. The problem happens when you are not in `subdir2`. Here is the solution:

```py
import pathlib

this_script = pathlib.Path(__file__)
json_path = this_script.parent / "childdir" / "file.json"
with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

Since `pathlib` is cross-platform, this code should work under Windows. I tested it under Mac and linux.

Answer (score 1):

First of all which OS are you using ? since windows uses `\` and UNIX based OSes use `/`

Bast approach would be to use path from os module like this:

```py
import os

with open(os.path.join('childdir', 'file.json'), 'r')" as f:
    # YOUR CODE
```

This is a better approach because it is platform independent since it creates the path appropriately based on the OS you are on.

Comment: I would add one more comment. maybe it will be helpful to find out what is your current working directory. If you are not in `subdr2 `, `FileNotFoundError` is likely to persist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the file you want to open is in the subdirectory of your current working directory(where the python file is present).
You need to consider 2 things here,

1. Depends on the OS which you're using, it's either '/' for UNIX-based &
   '' for Windows-based as separator in the file's path
2. we can either use the absolute path of the file and mode to open the file
   or with the path sub-module of that os module.

```
# With absolute path in Windows 
 with open('F:\parentDirectory\subdr2\childdir\file.json', mode(r/a/w..)) as fl:
         # logic
```

or

```
# with os.path submodule
  import os

  with open(os.path.join('childdir', 'file.json'), mode('r/w/a/..')) as fl:
        # logic
```